# Laravel combined with Vuejs, 2 routes to 1 route

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am building a listerpage in Laravel with Vuejs. Now i have to specify 2 routes. 1 laravel and the same in the vuejs routes. Is it possible to reduce this to 1 route?

Laravel global cms template:

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

Laravel route:

```
www.domain.com/admin/banners

Route::get(CMSURL.'/banners/', function (Request $request) {
    return (new BannerController())->index($request);
})->name(AdminRoutes::BANNERS);
```

Vuejs route:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/zcalendar/banners',
            name: 'banners',
            component: AppBanners,
        }
    ],
});
```

Comment: Could you describe the `use case`/`your goal` more? i'm afraid it is a bit unclear

Comment: @Quezler, i have a laravel app. For loading a listerpage or any other page i have to make 2 routes. One for laravel (because when reloading the url i am getitng an error that the oute doesn't exist) and one for loading the url for vuejs router-view. I just want to things ones not twice.

Comment: If i am understanding correctly you basically want to route all laravel urls to vue router, and have the routes defined there, correct?

Comment: @Quezler Almost, only specific routes. I don't want to define both /zcalendar/banners in Laravel and /zcalendar/banners inVuejs like example above.

Comment: what you could do is define a wildcard route with a certain prefix that always loads the vue router view, but if the routes are truly specific i'm afraid the only way would be to define them on the frontend as well as the backend, since laravel needs to know what urls to send to vue router, and vue router needs to know what to do with that url.

Comment: @Quezler I was afraid of that, thanks anyway!